# Token balance not reflected in metamask/Etherum wallet

Tags: tokens, metamask

I just had purchased of Eth to EoS coin through  metamask. I had the token address and confirmation number.
The problem is, I am not able to see this transaction in my ethereum wallet or in metamask. Anyone has the same issue? if so how did you guys manage it?

Comment: Try searching for your address in which you received the tokens on etherscan. If it shows you havr token balance, there is some issue with your wallet. If not,  just search for transaction hash(if you have one)  on etherscan and check if to adress is the address in which you think you received tokens.

Comment: thanks for your comment, probably the issue is in my wallet. have you guys purchased any EOS? Could EOS be kind of scam?

Comment: No, I have not purchased. I have not gone through this token. Not sure if it's a scam or not.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried https://ethplorer.io/ ? it has a Token Balances section where you should see the amount you hold for each token

Comment: I did, it shows the transaction, but it has to show this transaction in Metamask, but when I am using the token address, nothing happen